# Can HTML escape output natively with built-in functions?

Tags: html, security, xss

What I mean is, is there some functionality built into HTML that you can use to escape output? For example some sort of that tag that would tell the browser that that everything inside this tag should not be considered regular HTML, but treated as regular text.

I know there are things like Google AutoEscape and Microsoft AntiXSS but these are not built into HTML.

And if there isn't the obvious question is why? Since XSS is somewhat common and a well known type of attack that devs can easily miss, why isn't there functionality built into HTMLto prevent this and make it easy on the devs?

Comment: Given that it's a well known vector, any *competent* dev should be able to do the necessary items to prevent it, IMO.   Just like SQL - natively there's  nothing built-in to prevent SQL Injection attacks, but there are tools (like EF, parameterized queries, etc) that are leveraged to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: if you had a tag that marked it's contents as "not regular HTML", what happens if it's contents contain the end tag?  Do you allow it to be escaped?

Comment: @Tim Maybe something like parameterized HTML could be implemented? In the case of SQL a lot of tools are built in like PDO in PHP which helps the devs. I just think HTML/Javascript does not have equivalent tools built in, or I am just unaware of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is `<pre>` that  [displays its content literally:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

> The HTML `<pre>` element (or HTML Preformatted Text) represents
>   preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in
>   a non-proportional ("monospace") font exactly as it is laid out in the
>   file. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as typed.

However, it's not useful protection against XSS or other attacks, since the attacker could simply inject a closing `</pre>` and then go on doing whatever they want in the rest of the code, which will be interpreted as part of the document.

Security wise, there's no simple alternative to escaping the data you want to output on server side.